# Android: touch events not detected after toDataUrl call

Tags: javascript, android, html, html5-canvas

Sorry for my english, I'm from Argentina. I'm develop a HTML5 app with Eclipse. When program loads an image on IMG element the events **touchstart**, **touchmove** and **touchend** are properly detected. But when I need to rotate the image, I use a CANVAS and **toDataUrl()** method, then touch events seems not detected. The source code I use is like this (consider all objects, variables and functions well declared):

```
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

function loadImage(strFile, intDeg) {
  if (intDeg == 90) image.onload = function() { rotateImage(); };
  imagePhoto.src = strFile;
}

function rotateImage() {
  image.onload = function() { moveImage(); };
  canvas.width = image.height;
  canvas.height = image.width;
  context.translate(canvas.width, 0);
  context.rotate(90 * Math.PI / 180);
  context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  context.restore();
  image.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
}

image.addEventListener("touchstart", downEvent, true, true);
image.addEventListener("touchmove", moveEvent, true, true);
image.addEventListener("touchend", upEvent, true, true);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

(I now think this answer was on completely the wrong track. Sorry!)

The thing is, `toDataURL` is a synchronous, blocking API call. That means that while it is running, the browser isn't listening to anything else. Here's my guess as to what is happening:

1. You call `loadImage`. This sets the `onload()` handler and assigns `strFile` to `.src`
2. `onload` fires and calls `rotateImage`. We draw the image into the canvas, then block for a while in `toDataURL`.
3. We assign the result of `toDataURL` to `.src`
4. We return to step 2.

We're so busy rotating and converting to base64 and loading that we never get a chance to process events.

Three possible fixes, in order of preference:

1. Rotate the image into a canvas that is visible onscreen. This way you don't need the `image.src` and `toDataURL` bit at all. (alternatively, use css `transform: rotate(90deg);` and don't do the rotation in javascript at all. This might be trickier cross-browser)
2. Remove the `onload` event handler at the end of `rotateImage`, so you don't get stuck in the loop.
3. Use `canvas.toBlob` and `FileReader.readAsDataURL` instead of `Canvas.toDataURL`, so everything is nice and asynchronous. Note that chrome doesn't yet implement `toBlob`, so this may not be so helpful.

Comment: Sorry, in the code I forgot a line `image.onload = function() { moveImage(); };` (now fixed), so there is no loop. CSS is an alternative but image position properties that I use to move and resize the image don´t change with `transform` and this is a problem for next lines. Using directly canvas is not an option because the bug with `touch` events. Thanks.

Comment: Does a `<canvas>` tag really not fire touch events? That's pretty odd. Which android versions is that problem occurring on? Have you tried putting a `<div>` on top of the `canvas` to listen for touch events? I'm not sure about your argument that `moveImage()` will prevent a loop from forming; does `moveImage()` assign to `.src`?

Comment: There are problems handling `<canvas>` `touchstart` and `touchend` events, but the same code works fine with `<img>`. The function `moveImage()` only set the position of the `<img>` element. There are no loop and no hangs because the app still working after display rotated image. I will test the `<div>` idea. Thanks.

Comment: Using `<canvas>` to rotate/show the image inside a `<div>` to handle `touch` events instead using `<img>` works fine. However this implied a lot of new code. I don't check the question as solved because the original issue remains. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a bug in android before 4.1: http://developersday.wordpress.com/2012/08/17/missing-events-touchstartmoveend-and-scroll-on-android-4-0-x-and-earlier/

The super-short version is that touch events don't play well with scrolling. http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19827 suggests calling e.preventDefault() in your touch event handlers.

Comment: I thought it was just a `canvas` problem. Thanks.